# IMAGE EXCEPTION

Tags: java, image-processing

```
JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);
JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(bi);
JPEGImageDecoder decoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGDecoder(in);'
```

When I compile the code above it says that the `com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec` API may have been removed. How do I clear this warning? I am using Java version 6.

Comment: Well, do you want to remove the warning? If it really _is_ removed and the application crashes, but you never saw that warning, how could you tell what happened? But as long as it is a warning, try `@suppress-warnings()`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) for reading/writing and maybe encoding. The encoding parametrisation might not be up to Sun's implementation.

And yes, not every JDK/JRE goes with sun classes. So already now it is a portability issue.

Answer (score 0):

use BASE64 for encoding and decoding...